# Namenode not getting started on CentOS 7

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I have installed the Hadoop using Hortonworks data plataform. I have three machines running CentOS 7. One of those three computers is running the amabari-server and an ambari-client instance. The other two are running only the amabari-client.

All the installation process went fine until the NameNode Start task, which raises an error. The NameNode is running on the same machine of the amabari-server.

This is the error log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/namenode.py", line 401, in <module>
    NameNode().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/namenode.py", line 102, in start
    namenode(action="start", hdfs_binary=hdfs_binary, upgrade_type=upgrade_type, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons/os_family_impl.py", line 89, in thunk
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/hdfs_namenode.py", line 146, in namenode
    create_log_dir=True
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/HDFS/2.1.0.2.0/package/scripts/utils.py", line 267, in service
    Execute(daemon_cmd, not_if=process_id_exists_command, environment=hadoop_env_exports)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/base.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 158, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 121, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 238, in action_run
    tries=self.resource.tries, try_sleep=self.resource.try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ;  /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf start namenode'' returned 1. starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hadoop.out
```

The log above says :

> resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'ambari-sudo.sh su hdfs -l -s /bin/bash -c 'ulimit -c unlimited ;  /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf start namenode'' returned 1. starting namenode, logging to /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hadoop.out

But when I open the hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hadoop.out file, this is the content:

```
ulimit -a for user hdfs
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30513
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 128000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 65536
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I set bigger soft and hard limits for the user hdfs, but it did not work. I have formated the namenode, but it did not work too. So I tried reinstalling the server and the clients and it is still not working.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Are there any errors listed in /var/log/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-namenode-hadoop.log?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue - did you get any clues?

Answer (score 0):

After pulling out some hair I have gotten a workaround for me without necessarily understanding the whys just yet.  This seems to be something to do with DNS. When I add the hostname to the hosts file it resolves the issue, as opposed to depending on DNS for the current host. e.g.

```
172.16.1.34 hostname.domain hostname
```

This is odd as DNS works just fine to the host.  I am working from behind a proxy.